# simple program giving different results on linux vs on mac

Tags: c++, linux, macos

If I have the very simple program

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, uint32_t> test_map;
    test_map["test"] = test_map.size();
    std::cout << test_map["test"] << "\n";
}
```

and I compile and run it on my macbook, I get

```
(venv) gmoss$ clang test.cpp -lc++ -o test.out
(venv) gmoss$ ./test.out
0
```

and then, if I go and compile and run it on an aws machine with ubuntu, I get

```
ubuntu:/home/george$ g++ test.cpp -o test.out -std=c++17
ubuntu:/home/george$ ./test.out
1
```

this just cost me like a day and a half of work, one of those "all the tests pass on my box, but not in the docker image" situations.

what's the explanation and how to avoid issues like this in the future?

Comment: The language definition does not tell you whether `test_map.size()` will be called before or after adding `test_map[“test”]`. If it’s called before, you get 0; if it gets called after, you get 1.

Comment: @PeteBecker Actually, it's [specified](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1.sentence-5).

Comment: I learned C in 2002 and I always learned that assignment is right-to-left.

Comment: @cigien right, so doesn't that mean that the OSX result is "correct" and the GNU result is unexpected??

Comment: Sure, but c is a different language. The OSX result is irrelevant, because the behavior was only specified from c++17. The gcc result looks wrong. I'm seeing 0 [here](https://godbolt.org/z/b3YoTM).

Comment: why is it irrelevant? it's also compiled with c++17.

Comment: and i'm definitely seeing 1 in my case. sad day.

Comment: I wonder if you're using a version of `g++` that doesn't have full C++17 support.

Comment: @cigien — it’s specified **since C++ 17**. Absent a statement of which standard is being applied, it’s unspecified. And that’s obviously the correct answer here, since it explains the behavior.

Comment: Is `g++ test.cpp -o test.out -std=c++17` not a statement that the c++17 standard is being applied?